# Change order of monitors without changing fullscreen"size"

Tags: multiple-monitors, flash, fullscreen

I have a dual monitor setup. My primary monitor is a 22" with a max resolution of 1680x1050 and my secondary is a 19" with a max resolution of 1280x1024. The secondary is standing on the left side of the primary one.

My problem now is, that, if I change the order of the monitors in my nvidia x-server settings, so that my secondary is the first one (or the one on the left), the fullscreen mode in flash in scaled up to my secondary monitor, even if it´s displayed on my primary one. Meaning that i get a 1280x1024 "fullscreen" window on my bigger primary monitor. When I configure my x-server settings so the secondary monitor is the one on the right, I don´t have this problem. The only thing then is, that I have to scroll out on the right to get to my monitor on the right.

I can´t move my secondary monitor on the right side of my primary due to lack of space and my belief that there must be a software solution. ;)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is. Go to **System Settyngs** > **Hardware** > **Displays**, select a monitor and drag it to rearrange its placement:

[image: displays]

---

[image: displays]

Comment: Well, if I do this, videos get resized to, in this case, "laptop size" on the "AOC intl". If you have to screens of the same size, that is totally fine, but not in my case. But thanks for the answer anyways :)

Comment: @user171489 Where do you see in this case (my case) that videos get resized? They have stayed the same.